# Return a dynamically accepted value in function and use it in other function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I will be accepting a value dynamically from the user using a prompt on click of a button in one function. I need to return the input accepted from the user in the prompt and use that input in another function.

How can I return the value of one function in an `onclick` and pass that returned value to other function?

Please help me.

Comment: If you have your html markup and code, you should post that to clarify what it is you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you need to configure your functions to allow you to pass arguments. For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/guRQq/

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="The value from the button"/>
<input id="text" type="text" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        myOtherFunction($(this).val());
    });
});

function myOtherFunction(passedValue) {
    $('#text').val(passedValue);
}
```

This is using [jQuery](http://jquery.org), a javascript library. It works well with events.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a number of ways.

**Example 1** <sub>{</sub> // passing around values using arguments/params

```
<script>
    function showme(answer) {
        alert("You said your name is " + answer + "!");
        doSomething(answer);   
    }

    function doSomething(name) {
        alert("Second function called with the name \"" + name + "\".");    
    } 
</script>

<button onclick="showme(prompt('What\'s your name?'));">Click here</button>
```

<sup>}</sup>

**Example 2** <sub>{</sub> // Using global variables

```
<script>
    var name = "";

    function setName(answer) {
        // Set the global variable "name" to the answer given in the prompt
        name = answer;

        // Call the second function, without having to pass any params
        showName();  
    }

    function showName() {
        alert("You said your name was " + name ".");    
    } 
</script>

<button onclick="setName(prompt('What\'s your name?'));">Click here</button>
```

<sup>}</sup>

**Example 3** <sub>{</sub> // Simple method

```
<script>
    var name = "";

    function setName(answer) {
        // Set the global variable "name" to the answer given in the prompt
        name = prompt('What\'s your name?');

        // Call the second function, without having to pass any params
        showName();  
    }

    function showName() {
        alert("You said your name was " + name ".");    
    } 
</script>

<button onclick="setName();">Click here</button>
```

<sup>}</sup>